# how can I use multiple {% block content %} inside base template in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

So, I have this base html where for example I am using it like this

```
<html>
<body>
<nav> navbar </nav>
<div class= "content">
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
.............
```

My question is can I use multiple block contents in the same base html ? So that I can extend the parent and add elements in whatever block I want ?
like this -

```
<html>
<body>
<nav> navbar </nav>
<div class= "content">
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</div>

<div class = "summaries">
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
.............
```

Question might sound rookie. I am new to Django!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use two block tags with one name.

This is from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/):

> Finally, note that you can’t define multiple `block` tags with the same name in the same template. This limitation exists because a `block` tag works in "both" directions. That is, a `block` tag doesn't just provide a hole to fill – it also defines the content that fills the hole in the *parent*. If there were two similarly-named block tags in a template, that template’s parent wouldn't know which one of the blocks' content to use.

---

Just name it something else.

Comment: you guys are fast! thanks a lot!